# Digging deck footings next to pool

Tags: deck, pool

I’m starting to build a deck, however I’m not sure how close to the above ground pool is safe to dig.

I’m aiming to stay one full foot away   so  my 12” footing will have the center dig out at about 19” - 20” from the wall.
Due to the way the decking sits, I don’t think I can get much further than this.

**Will it be OK?**  Or am I still undercutting the pool too much.  **How close do you think is too close?**

For what it’s worth; 12” footings at 44” depth.  There are quite a few near the pool  so they are plenty large enough for the load.

Comment: Empty the pool during the work for the footings - reduces the load. Put markers in and take measurements prior and during to make sure nothing moves.

Comment: It’s a full above ground pool...  it cannot be emptied, without major risk to the liner.  That being said, there should be basically no horizontal load - just vertical

Comment: So the load on the soil is purely vertical - good luck with that.